# Bluetooth device gone? How to recover it?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I was 'playing' with the bluetooth device (because my d**n Apple Magic Mouse still disconnects from time to time - installing 'tlp', tweaking some things, doing reboots) when the bluetooth device 'disappeared'. Reaching the bluetooth config (dash > Bluetooth), the bluetooth was in disabled state but simply refuses to turn on.

This is weird: it was working in the beginning of the day. In the previous days, I've found its 'code' (output of 'lsusb'), which was '8087:07dc' (the last line of the following output):

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep 8087
Mar  6 08:44:05 feng-GGT-Latitude-E7440 kernel: [    1.165118] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
Mar  6 08:44:05 feng-GGT-Latitude-E7440 kernel: [    1.530835] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07dc
$
```

However, doing the same on a later syslog file (because the computer has been rebooted many times, and therefore has gone through the initialization process which discovers the devices), that device is gone (no more signs of the '07dc' product):

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep 8087
Mar  6 09:05:02 feng-GGT-Latitude-E7440 kernel: [    1.164789] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
Mar  6 09:21:32 feng-GGT-Latitude-E7440 kernel: [    1.164981] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
Mar  6 09:31:18 feng-GGT-Latitude-E7440 kernel: [    1.157447] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
$
```

I'm wondering whether that bluetooth adapter has gone dead or is this simply a configuration issue?

What else I can do to find out/resolve this issue?

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is probably a consecutive or your "play". It is next to impossible to find out what you broke. Fixing this disconnect on Intel devices is quite easy.

Comment: @Pilot6, I've played with 1) configuring the 'tlp', 2)  installed the 'indicator-cpufreq' and 3) sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove. And that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This was very weird... The laptop is not that old; it is a DELL LATITUDE E7440]

**The solution:**

1. go to the BIOS,
2. take any note of the current values from there, (because the next step will wipe them out).
3. reload the default values and
4. reboot.

**A bit more descriptive...**

One other attempt was booting using an Ubuntu installation image (to try the Ubuntu) - so that I could mimic a fresh install, to check whether the initialization process was able to find the Bluetooth device. Bummer: it also didn't found the device. Therefore, reinstalling the system from scratch, won't help.

Getting into the laptop's BIOS, it also reported that had no Bluetooth device.

Since I had nothing to lose, I decided to try reloading the 'defaults'. I had to do an reboot and.... for my surprise, after the boot, the BIOS's System Information screen was reporting that the system had a Bluetooth device! [On the previous paragraph, ie. bvefore reloading the default values, the same System Information reported that there was no Bluetooth device installed!!!]

Comment: So this issue is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not so sure, since the Bluetooth device disappeared _during_ my 'pĺay' with the components. Therefore, the question of 'who made/triggered the disappearance' still have to be answered; it might be caused by some software component [related to Ubuntu] or the notebook hardware/BIOS software].

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so very much!!!
I was believing my bluetooth device was broken, than this solved my problem.
Brief tips to make it simpler, you don't even have to get back to the default values: there are 2 sibling topics showing Bluetooth checkbox, under the "Wireless" topic. In which it may be activated, but the Bluetooth device anyway invisible. So you:

1. Go to the BIOS.
2. Uncheck "Bluetooth" inside the "Wireless switch" and "Wireless Device Enabled" topics.
3. Click the "Apply" button
4. Check back the "Bluetooth" points you've just unchecked.
5. Click the "Apply" button again
6. Reboot

Additional tip that I've found to explain my problem, so I leave for anybody who wants to avoid it: The "blueman" proprietary package. When you find it's worthless, you just try try to uninstall it and your Bluetooth device goes away. So just avoid this software and you might avoid the headache.